# tensorflow: predicting multi-label accuracy considering top-k predicted values

Tags: tensorflow

My set up is if given a set of data labels where some of them can have multiple ones (the max number of one's for each example is known denoted by n):

```
1,0,0,0,1,0
0,0,1,0,1,1
....
1,1,1,0,0,0
```

when I predict I want to see what are the indices for the top n logits are so if the prediction indices contains the label indices for all one's it's a correct prediction. How can achieve that in tensorflow?

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
#inputs 
labels = tf.constant([[1,1,0,0,0,0],[0,0,1,0,1,1]])
logits = tf.constant([[.6,.5,.5,.4,.2,0.1],[.05,.15,.2,.15,.05,.5]])
k = 2

# Predict the top-k for each row
topk, idx = tf.nn.top_k(logits, k)

# Sort the index for input to sparse_to_dense matrix 
idx, _ = tf.nn.top_k(-idx, k)

# Obtain the full indices
indices = tf.stack([tf.tile(tf.range(0, idx.get_shape()[0])[...,tf.newaxis], [1, k]), -idx], axis=2)
indices = tf.reshape(tf.squeeze(indices), [-1,2])

#convert them to dense matrix
pred_labels = tf.sparse_to_dense(indices, logits.get_shape(),   tf.ones(idx.get_shape()[0]*k))

#Calculate whether each row of labels contained in logits
sum1 = tf.reduce_sum(tf.cast(labels, tf.float32),1)
sum2 = tf.reduce_sum(tf.multiply(tf.cast(labels, tf.float32), tf.cast(pred_labels, tf.float32)), 1)
acc = tf.equal(sum1, sum2)
sess = tf.InteractiveSession()
print(sess.run(pred_labels))
sess.run(acc)

# Outputs
#[[ 1.  1.  1.  0.  0.  0.]
#[ 0.  1.  1.  0.  0.  1.]]

#[ True, False]
```

Comment: what if K = 3, labels = [1,1,0,0,0,0] prediction = [.6,.5,.5,.4,.2] so predicted indices are [0,1,2] and label indices are [0,1] in which case they did not match does your approach work?

Comment: What is your expected behaviour in this case?. if you want to use top n logits, how you want the acc to be?

Comment: as long as the labels indices is a subset of prediction indices it is a correct prediction

Comment: "when I predict I want to see what are the indices for the top n logits are so if the prediction indices contains the label indices for all one's it's a correct prediction" which part is not clear

Comment: changed the logic in calculating acc, check the code.

Comment: sure, go ahead with your questions

Comment: would you please break down `tf.tile(tf.range(0, idx.get_shape()[0])[...,tf.newaxis], [1, k]), -idx`?

Comment: You have indices like [[ 0 1 2] [1 2 5]] which needs to be converted to full indices [[0,0][0,1],[0,2]],[[1,1],[1,2],[1,5]] for the input to sparse_to_dense()